# Command line arguments with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, command-line, ide, codeblocks

So, I have been using CodeBlocks IDE for compiling my C and C++ programs. But I want to run the program from the command line. How do I go about this?
P.S I want to run it on Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a Code::Blocks workspace from the command line, use `codeblocks.exe --build --target=W32_Release --no-batch-window-close MyApp.workspace` where `MyApp.workspace` is your workspace. If you want to build a program from the command line without using Code::Blocks, use `gcc -O2 program.c -o program` where `program.c` is your program, or `g++ -O2 program.cpp -o program` for C++. You can get gcc & g++ from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).